# Aligning equations vertically with align enviornment

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

I am writing about tensors right now, and have to describe the merging of two states into a single tensor. Right now I have something that looks like this:
[image]
with the following code:

```
\begin{align}
    & r \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + & s \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + & t \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + & u \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
    \text{with the basis} & \biggr(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, & \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, & \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, & \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\biggr) \\
    \text{can be written as} & \Biggr(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, & \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, & \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, & \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\Biggr)
\end{align}
```

A couple of things bug me.

- The braces don't fit the matrices. (I tried `\left(` and `\right)`, but that doesn't work...
- Worst of all is that I can't get the columns to align vertically (Preferably centered)

Maybe something like this:
[image]

I have already tried everything I could think of, but I just can't get there...
If anyone has a suggestion, please comment!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{ r c c c c c c c l }
    r &
    \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} & 
    {} + s &
    \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} & 
    {} + t &
    \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} &
    {} + u &
    \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} &
    \\[10pt]
    \text{with the basis}\:\biggr( &
    \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} &
    , & 
    \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} &
    , & 
    \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} & 
    , & 
    \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} &
    \biggr) \\[10pt]
    \text{can be written as}\:\Biggr( &
    \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} &
    , & 
    \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} &
    , & 
    \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} & 
    , & 
    \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} &
    \Biggr)
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I would have never thought to use this environment. It works perfectly!

Comment: @MaximilianSchwärzler A tiny drawback is that you need to manually set the distance of the rows using `\\[10pt]`, because otherwise the matrices would stick to each other. `\arraystretch` cannot be easily used here, because it would also affect the matrices.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to pull the texts from the equation, where they don't belong in.

The alignment can be obtained with some tricks based on [`IEEEeqnarray`](https://moser-isi.ethz.ch/docs/typeset_equations.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\newcommand{\colv}[1]{\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}}

\begin{document}

The tensor
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rcCrcCrcCrcl}
r & \colv{1 \\ 0} \otimes \colv{1 \\ 0} & + &
s & \colv{1 \\ 0} \otimes \colv{0 \\ 1} & + &
t & \colv{0 \\ 1} \otimes \colv{1 \\ 0} & + &
u & \colv{0 \\ 1} \otimes \colv{0 \\ 1}
\\
\noalign{\vspace{2\jot}}
\noalign{\noindent with the basis}
\noalign{\vspace{4\jot}}
\biggr( &
  \colv{1 \\ 0} \otimes \colv{1 \\ 0}\mathrlap{,} &&&
  \colv{1 \\ 0} \otimes \colv{0 \\ 1}\mathrlap{,} &&&
  \colv{0 \\ 1} \otimes \colv{1 \\ 0}\mathrlap{,} &&&
  \colv{0 \\ 1} \otimes \colv{0 \\ 1} &
\biggr)
\\
\noalign{\vspace{2\jot}}
\noalign{\noindent can be written as}
\noalign{\vspace{4\jot}}
\left(\vphantom{\colv{0\\0\\0\\0}}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace &
  \mathllap{r}
  \colv{1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0}\mathrlap{,} &&&
  \mathllap{s}
  \colv{0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0}\mathrlap{,} &&&
  \mathllap{t}
  \colv{0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0}\mathrlap{,} &&&
  \mathllap{u}
  \colv{0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1} &
\left)\vphantom{\colv{0\\0\\0\\0}}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I added the scalars in the last row, remove them if you think better to.

The column types are

- `r` for a right aligned column
- `c` for a centered column
- `l` for a left aligned column
- `C` for a centered column with a binary operator or relation

Instead of `\mathrlap` (make a zero width box with content protruding to the right) and `\mathllap` (similar for left) I could have used `\IEEEeqnarraymulticol`, but that's a mouthful.